# splitting a string at arbitrary points lua

Tags: regex, string, lua, split, string-formatting

I would like to split a string at regular intervals in lua, and display each new string on a new line. My problem is that the split should happen after an arbitrary user defined number of characters, not at any special character. Currently my code is:

```
logfile = io.open("input.txt","r")
inputstring = logfile:read("*all")
for word in string.gmatch(inputstring, "TERRAIN_%a*") do 
j=1 
if j <= 64 then 
    io.write(word)
j=j+1
else
io.write(word,"\n")
    j=1
end
```

end

My intention is that each time string.gmatch finds a match, it will write it out to a new string and increment a counter. When the counter hits 64, it will insert a new line. I expect the lengths of the matches to be irregular.

I am not sure it is behaving as expected, or that this is the best approach to formatting a string like I want. Id appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you must initialize the counter outside the loop.

```
local logfile = io.open("input.txt","r")
local inputstring = logfile:read("*all")
local j = 0;
for word in string.gmatch(inputstring, "TERRAIN_%a*") do 
    j = j + 1;
    io.write(word);
    if j == 64 then
        io.write'\n';
        j = 1 -- reset the counter
    end
end
```

Comment: Ha - thanks. Output looks much closer to what I was expecting.